# What units for calculating wavenumber of a matter wave?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, units, dimensional-analysis, wave-particle-duality

So I have a problem where I need to calculate the wave number for proton of energy $40~\rm MeV$. I know the formula for wavenumber of a matter wave is $k = \frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{ \hbar}$. But what units do I need to use for these? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wavenumber is always related to the wavelength 
$$k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} .$$
Therefore, the units are *radians per meter*, which has dimensions of inverse distance.

The wavenumber is the magnitude of the propagation vector ${\bf k}$, which is related to the momentum ${\bf p}$ via the well-known relation
$$ {\bf p} = \hbar {\bf k} . $$ 
Momentum is related to energy and mass by (purely on dimensional basis)
$$ |{\bf p}| \sim \frac{E}{c} \sim m c. $$
So, one check that the wavenumber expression for matter waves, provided by the OP, produces the same dimensional relationship as the quantum relation between ${\bf p}$ and ${\bf k}$.

Comment: How do you go from mass, energy, and Planck's Constant to rads per meter...that doesn't make any sense

Comment: @flippiefanus How do you figure? It comes out to inverse meters.

Comment: Its the non-relativistic approximation of the wavenumber for a free particle using the deBroglie relations

Comment: As I stated, I am talking about matter waves, specifically electrons.

Comment: @Chris 'Radians' are formally dimensionless. So $\mathrm{rad/m}$ and $1/m$ are the same thing. It is, however, often useful to keep the pseudo-unit 'radians' in there to distinguish from $\mathrm{cycles/m}$ for wavelength. Flipiefanus: It would be better to be clear about that in the text of your answer.

Comment: @dmckee I was referring to the fact that trich42's formula has the correct units for a wavenumber. So I was asking about flippiefanus' statement "Not sure where you got that relationship from, it does not seem to have the correct dimensions for a wavenumber."

Comment: @Chris: sorry yes you're right. Didn't check it properly. Made some modifications to the answer.